# How to deal with warning : "Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default "

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have the -current- latest version of pandas, openpyxl, xlrd.

openpyxl : 3.0.6.
pandas : 1.2.2.
xlrd : 2.0.1.

I have a generated excel xlsx- file (export from a webapplication).
I read it in pandas:

```
myexcelfile = pd.read_excel(easy_payfile, engine="openpyxl")
```

Everything goes ok, I can successfully read the file.

But I do get a warning:

```
/Users/*******/projects/environments/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py:214: UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
```

The documentation doesn't shed too much light on it.

Is there any way I can add an option to avoid this warning?

I prefer not to suppress it.

Comment: It's a warning telling you that openpyxl might have to make some choices.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. That I can understand. Is there a way I can tell openpyxl what choice it has to make so it doesn't show this warning ?

Comment: No and the warning is self-explanatory: the workbook contains no stylesheet so openpyxl will use its default.

Comment: And this is a 'warning' because?

Comment: Because it's informational: the file might look different than you expect after processing. For example, number formats in the styles determine whether numbers are treated as dates or times.

Answer (score 28):

I don't think the `openpyxl` library offers you a way to disable it. You are going to need to use the `warnings` package directly.

A simple and punctual solution to the problem would be:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    myexcelfile = pd.read_excel(easy_payfile, engine="openpyxl")
```

Comment: Am I right in understanding that because of the "with", outside this clause we are not turning off the warnings?

Comment: @YGA That is correct.

Comment: Although this is a fair answer, I have added a new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77942784/) which uses warning filters using `category` and `module` conditions to avoid accidentally suppressing any unrelated warning.

Answer (score 7):

@ruhanbidart [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749978/10335) is better than mine because you turn off warnings just for the call to read_excel, but if you have dozens of calls to `pd.read_excel`, you can simply disable all warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

I know it isn't a good programming practice, but it can help to clean your output.

Comment: This ignores all warnings, not just that one (or close to it). It makes no attempt at selectivity. I am not referring to the timeframe of the suppression.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same warning. I just changed the sheet name of my excel file from "sheet_1" to "Sheet1", then the warning disappeared. I think pandas should fix this warning later.

Comment: This works for me. The default sheet name is `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 4):

`df=pd.read_excel("my.xlsx",engine="openpyxl")` passing the engine parameter got rid of the warning for me. `Default = None`, so I think it is just warning you that it using openpyxl for default style.

Comment: Specifying engine really doesn't make the warning noise any lower. Catching warnings does help as @ruhanbidart suggests.

Comment: Interesting that removed the warning for you Jose, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses a much narrower warning filter than in the prior [answer by ruhanbidart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749978/). In particular, it uses the `category` and `module` conditions to avoid accidentally suppressing any unrelated warning.

```py
import re
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module=re.escape('openpyxl.styles.stylesheet'))
    df = pd.read_excel(input_path, engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: I'd say to either supress the specific warning like this, OR wrap the read statement in a `with`, like @ruhanbidart does.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same warning and was unable to read the file. In my case the problem was coming from the Sheet name in the Excel file.

The initial name contained a `.` (ex: `MDM.TARGET`) I simply replace the `.` with `_` and everything's fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the sheet name. From Sheet0 I renamed it to Sheet1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my situation some columns' names had a dollar sign ($) in them. Replacing '$' to '_' solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just opened excel with Libreoffice, and saved the excel without doing any change on it. And it works wih no problem or warning. My excel is the images list on the image galery on Trendyol platform. So I guess this error is caused from something missing on code-generated excel, and this missing part is solved when we open file and save it again.