# Cant read all xlsx file using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

It should be 35 rows, but it give me only 1, if i resave the excel file everything work correct

```
stat = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=, read_only=True)
sheet = stat.active
print(sheet.max_row)
```

how can i solve this problem without resave?
There is also error

```
UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
```

Comment: I try it myself with my own excel file and there is nothing wrong. maybe it has something to do with your excel file

Comment: Yea it is, but i need to use these excel files.

Comment: try pandas library. pandas can read excel too. pandas still need openpyxl to read xlsx but it's alternative that might solve your problem

Comment: Please take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214951/how-to-deal-with-warning-workbook-contains-no-default-style-apply-openpyxls